# How to plot a point on mapwindowGIS

Tags: c#

i am using mapwingis and i have uploaded all the needed shape file..now i already have the data from the gps and i want to show it in my map. i had researched that i can use drawcircleex, but it does not give me the correct location and the circle is stucked in the center. heres my code:

```
 MapWinGIS.Shapefile plane = new MapWinGIS.Shapefile();// shape 1
        MapWinGIS.Shapefile roads = new MapWinGIS.Shapefile();// shape 2
        MapWinGIS.Shapefile gensan = new MapWinGIS.Shapefile();// shape 3
        MapWinGIS.Shapefile pois = new MapWinGIS.Shapefile();// shape 4
        MapWinGIS.Shapefile pofw = new MapWinGIS.Shapefile();// shape 5
        MapWinGIS.Shapefile places = new MapWinGIS.Shapefile();// shape 6
        MapWinGIS.Shapefile roadsfin = new MapWinGIS.Shapefile();// shape 7      
        MapWinGIS.Shapefile circle = new MapWinGIS.Shapefile();// shape 8 
        int shape1, shape2, shape3, shape4, shape5, shape6, shape7, shape8;

        public static string varname;




        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // layer of plane
            plane.Open("C:/Users/User/Desktop/THESIS/New Folder (2)/phi/philippines/adminareasfinal.shp", null);
            shape1 = axMap1.AddLayer(plane, true);
            axMap1.set_ShapeLayerFillColor(shape1, (UInt32)(System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle
            (System.Drawing.Color.Linen)));
            axMap1.set_ShapeLayerLineColor(shape1, (UInt32)(System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle
            (System.Drawing.Color.Linen)));

            // layer of gensan
            gensan.Open("C:/Users/User/Desktop/THESIS/New Folder (2)/gensan_southcotabato/gensan_southcotabato.shp", null);
            shape2 = axMap1.AddLayer(gensan, true);
            axMap1.set_ShapeLayerFillColor(shape2, (UInt32)(System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle
            (System.Drawing.Color.OldLace)));
            axMap1.set_ShapeLayerLineColor(shape2, (UInt32)(System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle
            (System.Drawing.Color.Black)));

            // layer of longitude and latitude
            Single LineWidth1 = 1;
            roadsfin.Open("C:/Users/User/Desktop/THESIS/New Folder (2)/phi/philippines/roadsfin.shp", null);
            shape7 = axMap1.AddLayer(roadsfin, true);
            axMap1.set_UDPointType(shape7, roadsfin);
            axMap1.set_ShapeLayerPointSize(shape7, LineWidth1);
            axMap1.set_ShapeLayerPointColor(shape7, (UInt32)(System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle
           (System.Drawing.Color.Transparent)));


            // layer of roads
            Single LineWidth = 2;
            roads.Open("C:/Users/User/Desktop/THESIS/New Folder (2)/phi/philippines/roads.shp", null);
            shape3 = axMap1.AddLayer(roads, true);
            axMap1.set_ShapeLayerLineWidth(shape3, LineWidth);
            axMap1.set_ShapeLayerLineColor(shape3, (UInt32)(System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle
            (System.Drawing.Color.White)));


            //layer of pois and pofw bitmap image
            Single pointsize = 1;

            pois.Open("C:/Users/User/Desktop/THESIS/New Folder (2)/phi/philippines/pois.shp", null);
            shape4 = axMap1.AddLayer(pois, true);
            pofw.Open("C:/Users/User/Desktop/THESIS/New Folder (2)/phi/philippines/pofw.shp", null);
            shape5 = axMap1.AddLayer(pofw, true);
            places.Open("C:/Users/User/Desktop/THESIS/New Folder (2)/phi/philippines/places.shp", null);
            shape6 = axMap1.AddLayer(places, true);


            int LineWidth7 = 10;
            circle.Open("C:/Users/User/Desktop/THESIS/New Folder (2)/phi/newshape/finalepoint.shp", null);
            shape8 = axMap1.AddLayer(circle, true);
            axMap1.set_ShapeLayerPointColor(shape8, (UInt32)(System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle
            (System.Drawing.Color.Black)));
            axMap1.set_ShapeLayerPointSize(shape8, LineWidth7);

            string circlelabel;
            double x12, y12;

            for (int j = 0; j < circle.NumShapes - 1; j++)
            {

                circlelabel = System.Convert.ToString(roads.get_CellValue(1, j));
                x12 = circle.get_Shape(j).Extents.xMin + (circle.get_Shape(j).Extents.xMax - circle.get_Shape(j).Extents.xMin) / 2;
                y12 = circle.get_Shape(j).Extents.yMin + (circle.get_Shape(j).Extents.yMax - circle.get_Shape(j).Extents.yMin) / 2;

                axMap1.AddLabel(shape8, circlelabel, (UInt32)(System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle
                        (System.Drawing.Color.Red)), x12, y12, MapWinGIS.tkHJustification.hjCenter);
            }


            MapWinGIS.Image poisimage = new MapWinGIS.Image();
            MapWinGIS.Image pofwimage = new MapWinGIS.Image();
            MapWinGIS.Image placesimage = new MapWinGIS.Image();

            poisimage.Open("C:/Users/User/Desktop/bitmap/poisimage.bmp", MapWinGIS.ImageType.USE_FILE_EXTENSION, true, null);
            {
                this.axMap1.set_ShapeLayerPointSize(shape4, pointsize);
                this.axMap1.set_ShapeLayerPointType(shape4, MapWinGIS.tkPointType.ptUserDefined);
                this.axMap1.set_UDPointType(shape4, poisimage);
            }
            axMap1.set_LayerVisible(shape4, true);



            pofwimage.Open("C:/Users/User/Desktop/bitmap/pofwimage.bmp", MapWinGIS.ImageType.USE_FILE_EXTENSION, true, null);
            {
                this.axMap1.set_ShapeLayerPointSize(shape5, pointsize);
                this.axMap1.set_ShapeLayerPointType(shape5, MapWinGIS.tkPointType.ptUserDefined);
                this.axMap1.set_UDPointType(shape5, pofwimage);
            }
            axMap1.set_LayerVisible(shape5, true);

            placesimage.Open("C:/Users/User/Desktop/bitmap/placesimage.bmp", MapWinGIS.ImageType.USE_FILE_EXTENSION, true, null);
            {
                this.axMap1.set_ShapeLayerPointSize(shape6, pointsize);
                this.axMap1.set_ShapeLayerPointType(shape6, MapWinGIS.tkPointType.ptUserDefined);
                this.axMap1.set_UDPointType(shape6, placesimage);
            }
            axMap1.set_LayerVisible(shape6, true);

            // the following are the codes to show the names of Roads

            string myLabel;
            double x, y;

            for (int i = 0; i < roads.NumShapes - 1; i++)
            {

                myLabel = System.Convert.ToString(roads.get_CellValue(4, i));
                x = roads.get_Shape(i).Extents.xMin + (roads.get_Shape(i).Extents.xMax - roads.get_Shape(i).Extents.xMin) / 2;
                y = roads.get_Shape(i).Extents.yMin + (roads.get_Shape(i).Extents.yMax - roads.get_Shape(i).Extents.yMin) / 2;


                axMap1.AddLabel(shape2, myLabel, (UInt32)(System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle
                        (System.Drawing.Color.Black)), x, y, MapWinGIS.tkHJustification.hjCenter);
            }

            // the following are the codes to show the names of pois

            string poislabel;
            double pois1, pois2;
            int handle = axMap1.NewDrawing(MapWinGIS.tkDrawReferenceList.dlScreenReferencedList);
            for (int ps = 0; ps < pois.NumShapes - 1; ps++)
            {

                poislabel = System.Convert.ToString(pois.get_CellValue(4, ps));
                pois1 = pois.get_Shape(ps).Extents.xMin + (pois.get_Shape(ps).Extents.xMax - pois.get_Shape(ps).Extents.xMin) / 2;
                pois2 = pois.get_Shape(ps).Extents.yMin + (pois.get_Shape(ps).Extents.yMax - pois.get_Shape(ps).Extents.yMin) / 2;
                double width = pois.get_Shape(ps).Extents.xMin + (pois.get_Shape(ps).Extents.xMax - pois.get_Shape(ps).Extents.xMin) / 2;
                double height = pois.get_Shape(ps).Extents.yMin + (pois.get_Shape(ps).Extents.yMax - pois.get_Shape(ps).Extents.yMin) / 2;
                axMap1.DrawCircleEx(handle, width, height, 5.0, 255, true);
                axMap1.AddLabel(shape4, poislabel, (UInt32)(System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle
                       (System.Drawing.Color.Black)), pois1, pois2, MapWinGIS.tkHJustification.hjCenter);

            }

            // the following is to display  the latitude

            string latitude;// longitude;
            double latx1, latx2;
            for (int counter = 0; counter < roadsfin.NumShapes - 1; counter++)
            {
                latitude = System.Convert.ToString(roadsfin.get_CellValue(1, counter));
                latx1 = roadsfin.get_Shape(counter).Extents.xMin + (roadsfin.get_Shape(counter).Extents.xMax - roadsfin.get_Shape(counter).Extents.xMin) / 2;
                latx2 = roadsfin.get_Shape(counter).Extents.yMin + (roadsfin.get_Shape(counter).Extents.yMax - roadsfin.get_Shape(counter).Extents.yMin) / 2;

                axMap1.AddLabel(shape7, latitude, (UInt32)(System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle
                       (System.Drawing.Color.Black)), latx1, latx2, MapWinGIS.tkHJustification.hjCenter);

            }

            // sample displaying of location
            // the following are the codes to show the names of pofw

            string pofwlabel;
            double pofw1, pofw2;
            for (int pf = 0; pf < pofw.NumShapes - 1; pf++)
            {

                pofwlabel = System.Convert.ToString(pofw.get_CellValue(4, pf));
                pofw1 = pofw.get_Shape(pf).Extents.xMin + (pofw.get_Shape(pf).Extents.xMax - pofw.get_Shape(pf).Extents.xMin) / 2;
                pofw2 = pofw.get_Shape(pf).Extents.yMin + (pofw.get_Shape(pf).Extents.yMax - pofw.get_Shape(pf).Extents.yMin) / 2;

                axMap1.AddLabel(shape5, pofwlabel, (UInt32)(System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle
                       (System.Drawing.Color.Black)), pofw1, pofw2, MapWinGIS.tkHJustification.hjCenter);

            }

           // the following are the codes to show the names of places

            string placeslabel;
            double places1, places2;

            for (int pl = 0; pl < places.NumShapes - 1; pl++)
            {

                placeslabel = System.Convert.ToString(places.get_CellValue(4, pl));
                places1 = places.get_Shape(pl).Extents.xMin + (places.get_Shape(pl).Extents.xMax - places.get_Shape(pl).Extents.xMin) / 2;
                places2 = places.get_Shape(pl).Extents.yMin + (places.get_Shape(pl).Extents.yMax - places.get_Shape(pl).Extents.yMin) / 2;               
                axMap1.AddLabel(shape6, placeslabel, (UInt32)(System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle
                       (System.Drawing.Color.Black)), places1, places2, MapWinGIS.tkHJustification.hjCenter);
            }

            double x_etchos = 125.141;
            double y_etchos = 6.117;

            double x_leche = 125.141;
            double y_leche = 6.117;

//            MapWinGIS.Extents ext = axMap1.Extents as MapWinGIS.Extents;
            double ewanko;

            for (int test1 = 0; test1 < roadsfin.NumShapes; test1++)
            {
                ewanko = System.Convert.ToDouble(roads.get_CellValue(4, test1));

                if (x_etchos > roadsfin.get_Shape(test1).Extents.xMin && x_etchos < roadsfin.get_Shape(test1).Extents.xMax && y_etchos > roadsfin.get_Shape(test1).Extents.yMin && y_etchos < roadsfin.get_Shape(test1).Extents.yMax)
                {
                    double width = roadsfin.get_Shape(test1).Extents.xMin + (roadsfin.get_Shape(test1).Extents.xMax - roadsfin.get_Shape(test1).Extents.xMin) / 2;
                    double height = roadsfin.get_Shape(test1).Extents.yMin + (roadsfin.get_Shape(test1).Extents.yMax - roadsfin.get_Shape(test1).Extents.yMin) / 2;
                    MessageBox.Show("width and height: " + width + " " + height);
                    //MessageBox.Show("x and y: " + ext.xMax + " <<max_X-min_X>> " + ext.xMin + " " + ext.yMax + " <<max_Y-min_X>> " + ext.yMin);
                    ext.SetBounds(x_etchos - width, y_etchos - height, 0.0, x_etchos + width, y_etchos + height, 0.0);
                    Application.DoEvents();


                    axMap1.ProjToPixel(x_etchos, y_etchos, ref x_leche, ref y_leche);
                    axMap1.DrawCircleEx(handle, x_leche, y_leche, 5.0, 255, true);

                }
}
```

Comment: Please formulate your question better. What have you tried? Did you get any errors? Where exactly are you stuck? Please don't post your entire code but only the relevant part.

Comment: the circle remains at the centre of the screen. as we zoom in the map, the circle still stays the in the centre and doesn't locate the correct location in the map

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this code is you are only calculating position and placement once. On load. You need to re-write the form class to handle zoom/pan events and re-calculate the shape positions and size.

Programs usually contain more than one function. the `application.doEvents` will process events in the queue but you aren't updating the shapes based on the events.

**TIP**

also things like

```
pofw1 = pofw.get_Shape(pf).Extents.xMin + (pofw.get_Shape(pf).Extents.xMax - pofw.get_Shape(pf).Extents.xMin) / 2;
pofw2 = pofw.get_Shape(pf).Extents.yMin + (pofw.get_Shape(pf).Extents.yMax - pofw.get_Shape(pf).Extents.yMin) / 2;
```

are easily put in a function since you call it multiple times in that function.

```
private Point getCenter( Extents ext ) {
   Point p; 
   p.X = ext.xMin + (ext.xMax - ext.xMin)/2.0; 
   p.Y = ext.yMin + (ext.yMax - ext.yMin)/2.0; 
   return p; 
}
```

called by

```
Point pofwPoint = getCenter(pofw.get_Shape(pf).Extents);
```

Comment: really? - i would have thought wapwingis would handle the redraw?